# Cython vs. Pure Python with Memoryviews

Tags: python, cython, memoryview

I'm just starting to learn Cython and I'm confused on an issue. If you look at the [main tutorial](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/cythonize.html) they have examples that show a "Pure Python" mode vs. "Cython" mode. The pure python mode uses the [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) type hints whereas the Cython mode introduces new keywords that aren't parsed by the python interpreter like `cdef` and you have to be sure to compile the `.pyx` file in one of the approved ways.

But I want to interact with NumPy arrays and algorithms. When I go to the most recent page on using  [Cython for NumPy Users](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#) there seems to be no mention of pure python modes. I don't know if that's because it's impossible with the `memoryview` approach detailed there or if the documentation is out of date. If I want to use NumPy arrays should I just constrain myself to using the Cython-specific syntax or is there some way of using the pure python mode as well that I'm not seeing?

Comment: The documentation is in the process of being updated to the pure Python mode so not all of it has been changed. Memoryviews should be usable from pure Python mode though if you want though. It'll just be a case of using `cython.double[:]` or similar in your annotation.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidW . So, for example, the tutorial says for a 2D memoryview to use `cdef int[:, :] result_view = result`. Instead I might do something like... `result_view: cython.double[:, :]` then `result_view = result`? For the lines like `cdef Py_ssize_t x, y` I imagine I would use `x: cython.Py_ssize_t` and `y: cython.Py_ssize_t`?

Comment: Yes, I believe that should work. If you want to use pure Python/annotations you're probably better off using the latest Cython 3 alpha release rather than the stable 0.29.x release just because it's something that is being actively improved and the main improvements are in the newer branch

Comment: I played with the example in the quickstart [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html). I was able to get the views that start with `narr` working with the above mentioned syntax, as well as the function, in pure python. I didn't see a way to do the `from cython.view cimport...` and then the associated `cvarray` and `carr` views. Perhaps that's as intended, I don't know enough to say, but I can see how those are C-specific.

Comment: I think you can write it to look like an import something like `from cython.cimports.cython.view import array`. It won't get you something that actually works as a Python script though, do it's debatable how useful it is.